# Can't connect my Ionic App with Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having problems when testing my Ionic App on Android devices... As you can see in the picture, on iOS all is OK but not in Android emulator.
[image: Preview of Apps]

I'm asking this because I tried with some tips on internet like Cordova Whitelist Plugin

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://www.ourentec.com/ourenapp/web/api/v1/*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://www.ourentec.com/ourenapp/web/api/v1/*"/>
```

And also in the Manifest.xml in Android Build folder

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I tried with `*` too but it does not work

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Any idea will be highly appreciated! :)

P.S: If it helps, the login works ok, but not the rest of $http Requests

```
$scope.login = function() {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: CONFIG.APIURL + '/access/',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;        charset=UTF-8'
        },
        data: $.param({
            email: $scope.data.email,
            passwd: $scope.data.password
        })
    };
    $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $cookies.put('user_id', response.data.user_id);
        $cookies.put('API_KEY', response.data.API_KEY);
        //redirect to customers main page...
        $state.go('tab.customers');

    }, function errorCallback(err) {
        //show error and delete password
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Acceso Denegado!',
            template: 'Email o contraseña incorrectos...'
        });
        $scope.data.password = '';
    });
}
```

SOLVED!!!

The problem was not Cordova-Whitelist-Plugin... The problem was that I was using AngularJS "ngCookies" and by default Android does not allow cookies in WebViews, so I replaced "ngCookies" with "ngStorage" (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) to store session and API_KEY info, and added that permission in the manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I hope this can help anyone in the same case! :)

Comment: Do you have a Content Security Policy meta tag in the head in your HTML file?  If you have whitelist issues, this would also come into play.

Comment: Yes, I tried with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *">` but still no working :(

Comment: It looks like the Android App does not execute the "getAllCustomers()" function after login... But I don't know why